# macos - terminal deleting parts of filepath beginning with "$"

Tags: command-line, terminal, osx

I'm trying to manipulate files in a directory whose filepath includes a directory that starts with "$", for instance:

```
git rm path/to/file/$dollarsigndirectory/anotherdirectory/file.format
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
fatal: pathspec 'path/to/file//anotherdirectory/file.format' did not match any files
```

EDIT: I've already tried using \$dollarsigndirectory and it simply says there isn't a directory called '\$dollarsigndirectory'

I've tried to troubleshoot but can't figure out why the '$' would make the directory invisible. Thanks!

Comment: Because `$dollarsigndirectory` is the value of the shell variable `dollarsigndirectory`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm relatively inexperienced with terminal. How would I distinguish between the shell variable and the directory when trying to access the filepath in a terminal command? I've tried using '\' before the dollar sign (I edited my question to reflect that)

Comment: You can surround the path with single or double quotes so that the `$` is not expanded.

Comment: Is that directory added to `git` in the first place?

Comment: @NasirRiley That seems to work, thanks so much!

Comment: @muru Yes, it is

Comment: @Dollarsignpredicament I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: Using a backslash to escape the dollar sign *should* work -- I have no idea why it isn't working for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can surround the path with single quotes so that the $ is not expanded.

Comment: Single quotes will work for this, but `$` expressions are still expanded in double quotes, so they will not work for this.

Comment: True. Double quotes will work if there are other special characters such as `'` `,` or `.` but not in this case. Edited to correct.